# Object in Render that I did not add

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

so my problem is a little bit weird.
If I try to render my "town of the future" (my geography project) then there is a plane I did not add. In the normal editing mode etc there is no plane but as soon as I start to render, the plane appears.
Any ideas?
[image: The Rendered Image]
[image: The Image before Rendering]

Comment: Blender has no reported ghosts  so far... so there is a plane somewhere in your scene that is probably disabled for preview (eye icon) but enabled for render (camera icon). If that is not the issue please report it to blender.supernatural.stackexchange

Comment: Then expect the apparition to to reappear every other day.  You will get used to dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Outliner if the visibility of this plane isn't hide If you find one simply delete it and hit render to see if it's oki.

Answer (score 1):

With your curser in the viewport press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show all hidden objects. Select the object and press <kbd>X</kbd> do delete it.